# Using Django REST framework with TCP Server socket

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, websocket, django-rest-framework

I am developing a web api using the Django REST Framework. At the same time, I am receiving stream data from IoT devices as an HTTP Post message. In this, I use tcp socket server in python. When I try to use these two things together, Django REST Framework does not work for HTTP requests, only the TCP socket works. How can I run Django REST Framework and TCP socket together?

TCP Server Socket code here:

```
class RFIDServer(Thread):
    def __init__(self, address="", port=8000):
        super().__init__()

        self.gateways = dict()
        self.tag_list = {}
        self.rfidData = dict()
        self.rfidDataLocker = Lock()

        self.address=address
        self.port=port
        self.socket_setup=False

        self.setup_socket()
    
    def setup_socket(self):
        try:
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        except:
            exit("Couldn't create a socket")
        try:
            self.sock.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        except:
            exit("Couldn't set socket options")
        try:
            self.sock.bind((self.address, self.port))
        except:
            print("Couldn't bind socket to server address")
            
        self.socket_setup=True


    def listen(self):
        if self.socket_setup!=True:
            print("Socket hasn't been setup. Do that first!")
            return
        self.sock.listen(1)
        while True:
            c, addr = self.sock.accept()
            threading.Thread(target = self.listenToClient, args = (c,addr)).start()
        self.sock.close()
            

    def listenToClient(self, c, addr):
        print('Got connection from', addr)
        opt = {
            "received_from": "client request",
            "body_required": True,
            "normalize_newlines": True
        }
        while True:
            data = c.recv(8196).decode("utf-8")
            try:
                parsed_data = python_http_parser.parse(data, opt)
                print(parsed_data['body'])
            except:
                print("Parsed Errors")
                print(data)

        c.close()
```

Comment: Do yourself a favor. Just back off, seriously. To deal with websocket decently, should use with Tornado. Treating raw sockets is too hard.

Comment: @AkihitoKIRISAKI I am currently using Django Rest Framework for http requests. I have no possibility to change this. If I use tornado tcpserver as you said, how can I integrate it with Django Rest Framework?

Comment: [tornado.wsgi](https://www.tornadoweb.org/en/stable/wsgi.html) is useful for it. Even an ancient repository, but there is [an example](https://github.com/bdarnell/django-tornado-demo). You will be able to see the outlook?